# python substring with unknown symbol

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string that I need to edit in python. Lets say the string is: `thisandthat+this`. The string could be any length.

Now pretend you don't know what/where in the string the special characters are. For example these characters: `+-)(*&^%$#@!`

How do I grab everything except for the special characters? So for the above example my result would be `thisandthatthis`.

Comment: is space counted as special?

Comment: @rock321987 yes a space is also special in this case. Basically everything other than a-z is special. Sorry about not being very specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If space is not included in special, you can use

```
''.join(re.split("[^a-z]", input_str))
```

You can also use `re.sub`

```
re.sub("[^a-z]", "", input_str)
```

Comment: I'm new to regex.. what is 'x' in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There's a brute-force way with a list comprehension:

```
orig = "thisandthat+this"
special = "+-)(&^%$#@!*"

cleaned = ''.join([x for x in orig if x not in special])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).  The re package in Python is designed to do exactly what you want. Python docs are this are very thorough and straightforward.  You can learn a lot about this powerful tool!

This will keep upper case string values.
If you only use [^a-z] upper case letters will be excluded.

```
import re

inputSTring = 'Some old String you put in here!'

word = ''.join(re.split("[^a-zA-Z]", inputString))
#or
word = ''.join(re.finall('[a-zA-Z+]', inputString))
```

This is very similar to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199398/extracting-only-characters-from-a-string-in-python) except you do not want to include spaces

Answer (score 0):

Without using `re`:

```
special = '+-)(&^%$#@!*'
s = 'thisandthat+this'
print(''.join(c for c in s if c not in special))
```

Using `re`:

```
not_special = re.compile(r'[^+\-)(&^%$#@!*]')
print(''.join(not_special.findall(s)))
```